# window.atob fails to decode string and throws an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, base64, blob

```
        function saveIMG(image) {
            var startIndex = image.indexOf("base64,") + 7;
            var b64 = image.substr(startIndex, image.indexOf(">") - startIndex - 2);
            var byteCharacters = atob(b64);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var data = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
            return "<img src='" + window.URL.createObjectURL(data) + "' width='150'/>";
        }
```

I wanted to use this code to encode a base64 image into an image with uses a URL. However, on the line where it uses `atob` it throws this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

I can only assume it is something to do with the base64, or perhaps it cannot convert base64 images using `atob`. Anyhow, here is the start of the base64 that was taken from the substring:

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/7RTuUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAA8cAVoAAxslRxwCAAACAAAAOEJJTQQlAAAAAAAQzc/6fajHvgkFcHaurwXDTjhCSU0EOgAAAAAA5QAAABAAAAABAAAAAAALcHJpbnRPdXRwdXQAAAAFAAAAAFBzdFNib29sAQAAAABJbnRlZW51bQAAAABJbnRlAAAAAENscm0AAAAPcHJpbnRTaXh0ZWVuQml0Ym9vbAAA`

Comment: Where did you got this `image.indexOf('>')` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here I'd say your problem is in substr second param:

```
 image.indexOf(">") - startIndex - 2
```

While the remaining of your code points toward a normal dataURI, this part implies the presence of a character that would not be valid in there (`>`).

So I strongly suspect that the value of this second param be  `-1 -16 -2` => `-19` and thus probably removing too much data which would make your base64 string invalid (e.g if it's length / 4 leaves 1 remainder).

So if you really have a valid dataURI, then all you need is to remove this second argument:

```js
function saveIMG(image) {
var startIndex = image.indexOf("base64,") + 7;
var b64 = image.substr(startIndex);
var byteCharacters = atob(b64);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var data = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
return "<img src='" + window.URL.createObjectURL(data) + "' width='150'/>";
}

// a black 300x150px JPEG image
var dataURI = document.createElement('canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var imgStr = saveIMG(dataURI);
document.body.innerHTML = imgStr;
```

Comment: Oops, yeah, I forgot to remove that, thank you! What a silly mistake!